# ASP.NET MVC 5 - Unit Testing Service that uses only Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have this class, that, actually, only does operations on top of ASP.NET Identity.

```
 public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
    {
        private readonly ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
        private readonly ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
        private readonly IAuthenticationManager _authManager;
        private readonly HttpContextBase _context;

        public AuthenticationService(
            ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, 
            ApplicationUserManager userManager, 
            IAuthenticationManager authManager,
            HttpContextBase context)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _authManager = authManager;
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<SignInStatus> SignIn(string email, string password)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(email, password, true, shouldLockout: false);
            return result;
        }

        public async Task<IdentityResult> Register(string email, string password)
        {
            var user = new AppUser
            {
                UserName = email,
                Email = email,
            };

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

            return result;
        }

        public void SignOut()
        {
            _authManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        }

        public async Task<IdentityResult> ForgotPassword(string email, string newPassword)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
            string resetToken = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);
            var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, resetToken, newPassword);

            return result;
        }

        public async Task<AppUser> GetUserByEmail(string email)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
            return user;
        }

        public string GetLoggedInUserId()
        {
            if(_context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return _context.User.Identity.GetUserId();
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

I don't know if I'm injecting the right dependencies. But my question is:

**In a class like this one, what would make sense to unit test? Since most methods call methods related to Identity and only return the result.**

The only test that it seems right to do is what happens when I try to get the ID of a user if no user is authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In almost any class you can test, assuming that it's a unit test of one entity under test and all internal dependencies(like `ApplicationUserManager` or `IAuthenticationManager`) are mocked:

1. All internal services are called exact number of times
2. The entity under test does not change arguments passed in a method, and correctly passes them into calls of internal services (like `ApplicationUserManager` or `IAuthenticationManager`)

So, for example, you can test in `SignIn` that `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` gets called exactly once and arguments are, for `email` and `password` — the same as they were passed into `SignIn`; for the third unnamed argument and `shouldLockout` — they are according to business logic — true and false.

`ForgotPassword` is trickier: you have data passed from `_userManager.FindByEmailAsync` to `_userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync` and then to `_userManager.ResetPasswordAsync`.
In this case, you don't need to test results of these three calls are correct as such thing should be tested in tests for `_userManager`, but you will need to test that calls to all these services are made exact number of times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!