# How to write a unit test for a method which calls other services

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I have a following method which is calling another service , but there is a some data manipulation before calling internal service.   Please see below

```
   public async Task<myObject> Save(string server,string username, myObject element)
            {
                string temp = element.Class + "_" + element.Description + "_" + username;
                var saveData = new string[] { element.Name, temp};
                var response = await datService.save(server, saveData);
                var result = response.TomyObject(); // this is the extension method to convert response to myObject. 
                return result ;
            }
```

What will be the best way to unit test?
I tried following but just want to make sure I am doing the "correct" way.

```
public async Task Save_Success()
        {
            //ARRANGE         
            var element = new myObject
            {
                Name = "Test",
                Description = "Test Save", 
                Class = "test class"


            };
            string temp = element.Class+ "_" + element.Description + "_" + username;
            var saveData = new string[] { element.Name, temp};
            var response = new anotherObject
            {

                Name= "Test",              
                MyArray = new objArray
                {
                    P0 = saveData[0],
                    P1 = saveData[1]                   

                },
                Error = ""

            };




            var datService = new Mock<IDataService>();
            datService.Setup(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string[]>()).Returns(Task.FromResult(response));
            var myClass = new MyClass(datService.Object);
            //ACT
            var result = await myClass.Save("testServer","testUser", element);
            // ASSERT
            Assert.AreEqual(response.MyArray.P0, result.Class);
        }
```

Here is the extension method

```
 public static myObject TomyObject(this anotherObject response)
        {
            var entity = new myObject();

            entity.Name = response.Name;           
           if(response.MyArray!= null && response.MyArray.P1 != "")
            {
                string[] details = response.MyArray.P1.Split('_');
                entity.Class = details[0];
                entity.Description = details[1];


            }

            return entity;

        }
```

Comment: Why do you stub `datService,Execute` if original method calls `datService.save`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET MVC 5 - Unit Testing Service that uses only Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61461179/asp-net-mvc-5-unit-testing-service-that-uses-only-identity)

Comment: sorry, that was typo. I changed the name for this post. I fixed it.

Comment: My main confusion is due to extension method, Do I arrange response from dataService so my extension method gives me the result I am expecting (like I did in my test) or there is another way to do this?

Comment: What extension method? Can't find any C# extensions in the code.

Comment: added to the post. I tried making simple example of my implementation which is causing me to miss on some details. sorry for the bad initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could test your extension method:

```cs
anotherObject response = new anotherObject
{
    Name = "TestName",
    MyArray = new objArray
    {
        P1 = "Val1_Val2"
    }
};
var result = response.TomyObject();
Assert.Equal("TestName", result.Name);
Assert.Equal("Val1", result.Class);
Assert.Equal("Val2", result.Description);
```

The key is to have your unit tests only test one unit of work. If you want to test your extension method, write a test for it *in isolation*. Once you start including multiple units of work (i.e. the `IDataService`), you are actually testing a system and it becomes an integration test.

**UPDATE:**

On this line in your `Save_Success` test:

```cs
// ASSERT
Assert.AreEqual(response.MyArray.P0, result.Class);
```

You are actually testing something that is not the responsibility of the `Save` method (setting the `Class` property is actually the responsibility of your `TomyObject`, which could be tested separately).

To verify the `Save` method is doing what it's supposed to, you could do this:

```cs
// ASSERT
datService.Verify(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string[]>()), Times.Once);
```

That way, you're only testing that the `Save` method is doing what it's explicitly responsible for doing.

Comment: So the way I am doing unit testing is correct? I can arrange the response from IDataService to my get expected result?   And then different unit test for Extension method?

Comment: @user2918107 I added some extra info in the answer. Hopefully that helps

Comment: Thank you so much, this what I was looking for.